# What is the use of '\u' and why does my program print a different value if I use quotes or not?

Tags: java

In the following code snippet :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = \u0030;
    System.out.println(a); // A
    int b = '\u0030';
    System.out.println(b); // B
}
```

Statement A is printing `0` whereas statement B is printing `48`.

Why is there a difference when I use single quotes?

Also, if a change the declaration for `a` to:

```
int a = \u0029;
```

Why do I get the error?

```
Syntax error on token ")", invalid VariableInitializer
```

Comment: What is your expectation when printing the corresponding ASCII value?

Comment: Seems correct. `030` [is character 0](https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character). What is confusing here?

Comment: Code is fine `\u0030` is the ASCII code 0

Comment: If you call code that behaves as designed annoying you'll have a hard time being a software developer...

Comment: @Reimeus : Means what does **' \u' ** means and why it is giving compilation if i use any number for below 30 and more then 40.Can you please explain.

Comment: exception when i use \u0029 is **Syntax error on token ")", invalid VariableInitializer**

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
int a = \u0030;
```

The string `\u0030` is the *number* literal `0` in your source code. It's as if you literally typed 0 instead.

> why it is giving compilation [error] if i use any number for below 30 and more then 40.
>
> exception when i use \u0029 is `Syntax error on token ")", invalid VariableInitializer`

Characters 0x30 to 0x39 are digits 0-9, which of course are literals you can assign to an `int`. The others are not valid integer literals.

Your compilation error example:

```
int a = \u0029;
```

Is the same as:

```
int a = ); // clearly not valid!
```

Going back to your original example, perhaps you meant:

```
int a = '\u0030'; // notice the single quotes
```

Now you are assigning a *character* literal to an integer. *Now* you can assign other characters, not just unicode `0x30`-`0x39`. Note that the integer will have the ordinal value of that character. So the variable `a` in this case would be 0x30 or in decimal 48.

Comment: Frank:It mean \u is used to denote unicode symbol in java source file.Nothing more then this ? @Frank Wilson

Comment: Yes exactly. They can appear anywhere in your source, not just in string or character literals. You could write your entire program code as unicode escape sequences, it just wouldn't be very readable!